# Referring external css in rails : No route matches [GET] error

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a `colorbox.css` stylesheet in my `vendor/assets/stylesheets`. If i want to use it in one of my view files in `app/views/account/view1.html`, How can I refer it?? Similarly with a js file in `vendor/assets/javascripts`. I tried the several options but none worked I still get the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/asset/stylesheets/colorbox.css"):
```

and

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/asset/javascripts/jquery.colorbox.js"):



<link rel="stylesheet" href="WHAT TO ADD HERE" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="WHAT TO ADD HERE"></script>
<script>
```

***Can anyone tell me how to refer the css file or any config changes need to be done?***
I'm running in  dev mode and using ruby 1.9.3 n rails 3.2.9

**EDIT:**

Mentioned only file names in the `src` and `href` attributes above.
Added require statements to `application.js` and `application.css.`
Added the following to `application.rb` as suggested by @sevenseacat

```
config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.colorbox.js', 'colorbox.css']
```

I still got the `No Route Matches Error`

When I changed the code in my view as

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :colorbox -%>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.colorbox" %>
```

The assets were served:

```
Started GET "/assets/colorbox.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 14:24:45 +0530
Served asset /colorbox.css - 304 Not Modified (11ms)
[2013-11-20 14:24:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.colorbox.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 14:24:45 +0530
Served asset /jquery.colorbox.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-11-20 14:24:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

**In my view:**

```
$(".group1").colorbox(({inline:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"}); ---in <head>
<p><a class="group1" href="/images/download.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p> --- in <body>
```

Still the image opens in a new page and not in a lightbox But because the context of this question was adding external css files, I guess **this is solved** :)

Comment: Use `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`, eg. `stylesheet_link_tag 'colorbox'`. Make sure any files you include like this are added into your precompile array (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets for details). Rails will do the rest.

Comment: I tried that too , I surely didnt get any error :) but the colorbox doesnt work.. The image still opens in a new page.. Lemme now check the precomplilation

Comment: You only need to worry about precompilation when it comes to deploying to staging or production, but it's still important to know. So the JS starts loading properly if you include it this way?

Comment: Please refer my EDIT section .. (Earlier i had missed a <script> tag and hence weirdly it showed error only for css..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Added `require` statements to `application.js` and `application.css`.
2. Added the following to `application.rb` as suggested by @sevenseacat

   config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.colorbox.js', 'colorbox.css']
3. I changed the code in my view as below:

code:<%= stylesheet_link_tag :colorbox -%>

code:

code:<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.colorbox" %>

The assets were served:

```
Started GET "/assets/colorbox.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 14:24:45 +0530
Served asset /colorbox.css - 304 Not Modified (11ms)
[2013-11-20 14:24:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.colorbox.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 14:24:45 +0530
Served asset /jquery.colorbox.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-11-20 14:24:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. S
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check existing your vendor path include rails console:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths.each do |path|
   puts path
end
```

Also you can try restart your ails server after creating the vendor/assets/stylesheets directory.

**Edit:**
if you want add stylesheet file only to one view you can add to application layout:

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

Then use a content for block in your view:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag :my_css -%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I checked  and it exists in the path... and i have restarted my server too.. Still i get that error.. Please tell me how to give the path in href or src??

Comment: I don't like if problem not resolved:) YOu still have issue "No route matches [GET]"? any time? What do you have in your application.css and  application.js. you can add file like "*= require colorbox" all or tree  *= require_tree vendor( and symilar for js: "//= require jquery.colorbox" and "//= require_tree vendor")

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  Adding the "//= require_tree vendor" threw an error like "require_true argument shud be a relative path".. when i gave "//= require_tree ../../vendor" it said "require_true argument shud be a a directive".. Please refer the EDIT section..

Comment: maybe try use gem which integrate with colorbox: "https://github.com/stevo/colorbox-rails"

Comment: Yeah i tried.. But it didnt give many options to play with so I left it :)