# Rails 3.2.13 - No route matches [GET] "/js/jquery.fancybox.js"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was assigned with the task of integrating new designs into an old app , the app was built on 3.2.8 and i did an upgrade to 3.2.13 . What puzzles me is the js part , i have done everything i could by searching on SO and vice versa but no luck .Already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471305/rails-no-route-matches-after-assetsprecompile)   and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048133/referring-external-css-in-rails-no-route-matches-get-errorsolved) but somehow the js isn't being served .Following are the parts of code that might be useful -

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb :

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "html5shiv.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "fancybox.js" %>
```

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/fancybox.js"></script>
```

**Error I get:**

```
  Started GET "/js/jquery.fancybox.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-14 17:17:33 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/jquery.fancybox.js"):
```

**Updated Error -**

```
Started GET "/assets/html5shiv.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-14 17:17:33 +0530
Served asset /html5shiv.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2014-05-14 17:17:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Any suggestion or pointers are most welcome . More details will be provided on asking .Thanks in advance , hoping to get it solved :)

Comment: why you are including `fancybox.js` in two places?. above two file will not simulate the error `No route matches [GET] /js/jquery.fancybox.js` because the path specified in the error message and the path specified in these files are different.

Comment: The error you have in your title won't match what we're seeing the code your posted. Could you copy and paste the exact error you're getting ?

Comment: above mentioned code didn't include the `jquery.fancybox.js` file. Check the error log, it will show the file name and line number.

Comment: Updated with the error

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not sure why you're including your scripts **twice** but I would recommend against it. Secondly, are you using the asset pipeline? If you are (and I strongly recommend that you do) simply add the following to your `application.js` file:

```
//= require html5shiv
//= require fancybox
```

And the correct files should be included in your concatenated javascript file.

Also, the error you're receiving doesn't seem to be connected to the code you posted (as you specify no links to assets living under `/js`), but I do believe that when you attempt to link to scripts living at `/javascripts` (as opposed to `assets/javascripts`) you might get a routing error like the one you posted.

So, remove the references to your scripts and simply add them to your manifest (`application.js`) and you should be fine.

Comment: So you have added the two lines I listed to your manifest file and removed references to the scripts in other parts of your code? If so, then could you see where `/js/jquery.fancybox.js` is called from? Is one of your scripts referencing it, perhaps? Try to search your entire project for references to this file.

Comment: Isn't /js the same place as /assets/javascripts ?

Comment: @Kumardev I'm not sure about the naming conventions for assets in Rails < 4, but at least in 4 and up (as far as I know) `/assets/javascripts/` is *not* the same as `/js`. About your new error: do you have `html5shiv` installed as a gem or do you have a `html5shiv.js` file in your `assets/javascripts` folder?

Comment: i have it as html5shiv.js in javascripts folder, i did tried installing the fancybox gem but the error was still there .

Comment: So now you only have references to your javascript files in your `application.js?` file, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52682/discussion-between-nicolay-and-kumardev)